# ASP razor's WebImage helper not saving photos

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm trying to make a page where users can upload photos, I am using asp's WebImage helper and the problem is the photos do not get saved in the images folder of the website....this is the code I used

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post pictures of code but write out your code. This is hardly legible.

Comment: Also, share some of your razor view, especially the bit where your form starts